# Best way to create the Instances in an Activity in android, without using butterknife and Databinding

Tags: android, butterknife

Ihave used Two ways of creating instances in android activity. which one is better way, Method 1 or 2.

**Method 1:**

```
//Global instance

    Button btn;

    //Inside Oncreate

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

    //some other Place 
    btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
    btn.setText("Hai");
```

**Method 2:** //In the places where it is Required

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.btn)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

((Button)findViewById(R.id.btn)).setText("Hai");
```

**Butterknife** and **Data Binding** not required.

Comment: can be closed as dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088146/is-it-good-to-call-findviewbyid-every-time-in-activity-lifecycle-whenever-requir

Answer (score 9):

The method #1 is better in performance that the another one, because you only execute the method `findViewByID` once. This method is responsible for searching the view in the hierarchy of the parent layout. When the Activity is destroyed the garbage collector will deallocate the memory of button instance.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go with **Method #1**, since call [`View#findViewById(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) each time you want to access is a *costly* operation, as each time you call the method, the whole *view hierarchy* needs to be traversed in order to find the `view`.
So the way is to do it once and store a reference to the view in your Activity class, either inside your `Activity#onCreate()` or a first-time you need to access the view (although, it's better to do in `onCreate()` as it's much cleaner).

Finally, to find the view, you can,

- For Target API < 26,

  ```
  Button mSignUpButton;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    // regular stuff

    this.mSignUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupbutton);
  }
  ```
- For Target API >= 26 and Android studio version 3 and above,

  ```
  Button mSignUpButton;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    // regular stuff

    this.mSignUpButton = findViewById(R.id.signupbutton);
  }
  ```

  With API 26 and Android Studio 3, Google introduced compiler support to automatically cast the `view` into appropriate sub-type.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to question is not much clear. You are asking about Activity instance or Instance of views in Activity.

If you are finding a better way to instantiate activity view elements & don't want to use Butterknife or Databinding or any other lib. Then go with Method 1 which is more efficient than method 2. It is more reduced code boilerplate in method 1 than the method 2 & it will more be optimized to an Invalid state of the view.

```
Button btn;
//Inside Oncreate
btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
```